# What does it mean to have 2000 qubits and 6016 couplers?

Tags: d-wave, annealing, optimization, graph-states

From official [D-Wave docs](https://docs.dwavesys.com/docs/latest/c_gs_1.html):

> The D-Wave 2000Q QPU has up to 2048 qubits and 6016 couplers.

For example, I have the optimization problem defined as the QUBO problem.

If I want to solve it on D-Wave, does it mean that my problem has to have at most 2048 variables (vertices) and no more than 6016 mutual dot products between variables (edges)?

Answer (score 2):

The vertices and edges are the number of qubits and connections in DWaves quantum processing unit topology. It is called Chimera Graph, [see DWaves docs](https://docs.dwavesys.com/docs/latest/c_gs_4.html#chimera-graph) .
The graph is not fully connected.
Therefore an embedding of the qubo problem has to be done. It is done heuristically, [see minorminer docs](https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/en/stable/docs_minorminer/source/sdk_index.html).
As an example, if your problem is fully connected, the maximum number of variables in the qubo problem is currently 120 [DWaveCliqueSampler.largest_clique](https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/en/stable/docs_system/reference/samplers.html#dwavecliquesampler). If you try to submit something bigger you get:

```
DWaveClique ValueError  :  Cannot embed given BQM (size 128), sampler can only handle problems of size 120
```

For sparse problems an embedding can be found for more than 120 variables. So it really depends on the problem structure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes for QUBO problems, vertices of the graph are qubits, and edges of the graphs are "couplers" which couple two qubits together.

For example for the QUBO problem:

$$\tag{1}
b_1b_2 - 3b_1b_3 + b_3,
$$

you need a machine with 3 qubits and 2 couplers (one between qubits 1 and 2, and one between qubits 1 and 3).